# javascript: cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm trying to fill up an Array with a number of elements given by the user. I'm doing this with a prompt window.
However, the code doesn't execute, and I get an error on line 9, telling me this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at fillArrayWithNumberOfElements (line 9).

I searched for an answer online, but they are all pointing out that the array is not properly declared, while I'm pretty sure mine is.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
var emptyArray = [];

function askInput() {
    return (prompt("Please enter a number: "));
}

function fillArrayWithANumberOfElements(array, numberOfElements){
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
        array[i].push(askInput());
    }
    return array;
}

fillArrayWithANumberOfElements(emptyArray, 5);
```

Comment: array[i] is not an array so there is no push method defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `fillArrayWithANumberOfElements`, `array` is the array, not `array[i]`. So to push, just use

```
array.push(askInput());
```

not

```
// Not this
array[i].push(askInput());
```

Alternately if you like, use assignment:

```
array[i] = askInput();
```

Answer (score 0):

`push` is a function attached to the prototype of the `array` type. You're accessing a specific element within the array.